# Group by and Select Distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the differences between the following two queries?

```
SELECT distinct(Invalid_Emails), [leads_id] 
FROM [dbo].[InvalidEmails_stg] 
ORDER BY LEADS_ID DESC
```

vs

```
select invalid_emails, max(leads_id) as id 
from invalidEmails_stg 
group by invalid_emails 
having count(*) < 2 
order by id desc
```

The second one gave me fewer rows than the first.

Comment: maybe there are some invalid_emails that are HAVING >= 2?

Comment: what do you want to do? give some more details please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused by the parentheses in the first query.  They are doing nothing, so write the query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Invalid_Emails, leads_id 
FROM [dbo].[InvalidEmails_stg]
ORDER BY LEADS_ID DESC;
```

This returns all pairs of `Invalid_Emails`/`Leads_id` that appear in the database.  No matter how many times a given pair appears, it will be in the result set exactly one time.

This query:

```
select invalid_emails, max(leads_id) as id 
from invalidEmails_stg 
group by invalid_emails 
having count(*) < 2 
order by id desc;
```

Returns `invalid_emails`/`leads_id` pairs that occur only once in your data.  It filters out any pairs that occur more than once.

Here is a simple example:

```
invalid_emails   leads_id
    a@b.com         1
    a@b.com         1
    b@c.com         2
    b@c.com         3
    d@e.com         1
```

The first query will return:

```
    a@b.com         1
    b@c.com         2
    b@c.com         3
    d@e.com         1
```

`a@b.com` is returned once because duplicates are removed.

The second will return:

```
    b@c.com         2
    b@c.com         3
    d@e.com         1
```

`a@b.com` is not returned because it appears twice.

Answer (score 1):

In first query

```
SELECT distinct(Invalid_Emails),[leads_id] 
FROM [dbo].[InvalidEmails_stg] 
ORDER BY LEADS_ID DESC
```

you dont Check Constraint `< 2`

Actually in Second query :

```
select invalid_emails, max(leads_id) as id 
from invalidEmails_stg 
group by invalid_emails 
having count(*)<2 
order by id desc
```

if result Contain two or more than row `Having Count(*)` Filter Your Result .

another diffrence is `NULL`  value . if Column Invalid_Emails having `Null` Value Appear in First Query and Filter By `group by` in Next Query

Comment: theres no null or none in the table

Answer (score 0):

The queries have similar intent, to get a invalid_emails by leads_id.

The 2nd query uses aggregate functions to only bring back the maximum leads_id, and uses a having clause to remove duplicates.

Comment: does the first one not remove dups?

Comment: The first doesn't remove dupes, but it does use distinct.  They are pretty much doing the same thing in different ways.  You can probably look at the query results and compare the delta records to understand how they are working and chose the one that best meets your need.